# Select shapes within a range and align them

Tags: vba

I want to write a function where I can select one shape after which a macro aligns all the shapes that are within a 'short range' of the selected shape.

Therefore I wrote the following code that selects all the object within a range:

```
Sub Shape_Dimensions()

Dim L As Long
Dim T As Long
Dim H As Long
Dim W As Long

With ActiveWindow.Selection
    If .Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
        L = .ShapeRange.Left
        T = .ShapeRange.Top
        H = .ShapeRange.Height
        W = .ShapeRange.Width
    Else
        MsgBox "You have not selected an OBJECT in PowerPoint to dimension."
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

 'Set range for selection
 TopRange = L + 30
 DownRange = T + H + 20
 'Left and right are 0 - 600

End Sub
```

Now the final step I want to take is select all shapes that are within the top range and down range and align them with the top of the selected box. Any thoughts on how I should proceed?

Comment: It is pretty straightforward to loop over all the shapes on a slide .  Did you try that?

Comment: @Tim, but how do I align all the parts that are within the segment?

Comment: You change their Top and/or Left properties

Comment: Could you please provide an example? Im not following you...

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Shape_Align()

    Dim L As Long
    Dim T As Long
    Dim H As Long, TopRange As Long, DownRange As Long
    Dim W As Long, s As Shape, n As String

    With ActiveWindow.Selection
        If .Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
            L = .ShapeRange.Left
            T = .ShapeRange.Top
            H = .ShapeRange.Height
            W = .ShapeRange.Width
            n = .ShapeRange.Name
        Else
            MsgBox "You have not selected an OBJECT in PowerPoint to dimension."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

     'Set range for selection
     TopRange = L + 30
     DownRange = T + H + 20
     'Left and right are 0 - 600

     For Each s In ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes
        If s.Name <> n Then
           'in scope for lining up?
           If Abs(s.Top - T) < 60 Then
               s.Top = T
           End If
        End If
     Next s

End Sub
```